# Docker: Dockerizing apache virtual hosts

Tags: docker

After playing around with docker for a week or so, I thought it may be a good idea to dockerize my 4 Apache virtual hosts, each in its own container. I will then have NGINX in front (also in a container) to proxy to these virtual hosts based on domain name.

My question is, since I am going to run NGINX and 4 full instances of Apache, will that not be much more of a resource hog, than having one Apache instance (not dockerized) with 4 virtual hosts?

On the other hand, I will be able to tweak the Apache configuration for each vhost in a container on an individual basis, which would make sense as some sites are much more busy than others.

What would be best practices be in this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It does depend on how you configure apache; by default apache is configured to use lots of resources; you could decide to tune-down your apache configuration to use less resources, and spin up more instances (containers) if more capacity is needed.